# Number in newtheoremstyle is not italic

Tags: theorems, italic

I defined and used a new theormestyle using amsmath package:

```
\newtheoremstyle{standard}
  {\topsep}      % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}      % BELOWSPACE
  {\normalfont}  % BODYFONT % \itshape
  {0pt}          % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\itshape}     % HEADFONT
  {.\ }          % HEADPUNCT
  {0pt}          % HEADSPACE. `plain` default: {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
  {}             % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
```

When I see it correctly this leads e.g. to *Remark* 1. instead of *Remark 1.*
So the number is not italized. How should I do that?
Maybe internally the `\emph` environment is applied to the number, neutralizing italics already in place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}}             % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm,amsfonts}
\newtheoremstyle{standard}
  {\topsep}      % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}      % BELOWSPACE
  {\normalfont}  % BODYFONT % \itshape
  {0pt}          % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\itshape}     % HEADFONT
  {.\ }          % HEADPUNCT
  {0pt}          % HEADSPACE. `plain` default: {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
  {\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}}             % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\theoremstyle{standard}
\newtheorem{thm}{Remark}
\begin{document}
  \begin{thm}
    Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an interval.
  \end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]